# No viable alternative at input 'create external' while creating partition using athena

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena

I have stored partitioned data in s3 in hive format like this.

`/bucket/date=2017-02-20
/bucket/date=2017-20-25`

Now i am running following query from Athena to create partition

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive3(
    battery double,
    longitude double,
    application string,
    latitude double,
    device_id string,
    trip_id string,
    id int,
    accuracy double,
    PARTITIONED BY (date string) 
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format' = '1') LOCATION 's3://bucket/'`

Throwing following exception

`no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 6a4e0852-f8b0-11e6-b606-e52f2622374b)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PARTITIONED BY (date string)` should be outside the columns definition scope

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive3(
    battery double,
    longitude double,
    application string,
    latitude double,
    device_id string,
    trip_id string,
    id int,
    accuracy double
  )
PARTITIONED BY (date string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format' = '1') 
LOCATION 's3://bucket/'
```